# How to get the value of an item from database and set it as the spinner value

Tags: android, database, spinner, android-arrayadapter, simplecursoradapter

I have a database and the database populates a listview. when i long press a list item from the listview i get a context menu where i have the option to edit. When the edit option is clicked i open an activity and get all the values of the respective fields from the database. Now, here I want to get a value from the database and show it in the spinner. the spinner already has these values and is getting populated from the database... I have tried the following, but i get an error saying I can't cast a SimpleCursorAdapter to an ArrayAdapter..

```
        String osub = cursor.getString(Database.INDEX_SUBJECT);
        Cursor cs = mDBS.querySub(osub);
        String subs = cs.getString(DatabaseSub.INDEX_SSUBJECT);
        if(cs!=null){
            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdap = (ArrayAdapter<String>) subSpinner.getAdapter();   
                              //cast to an ArrayAdapter

            int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(subs);

            //set the default according to value
            subSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Please tell me how to do this.. Thank you.. I am relatively new so please let me know if I am overlooking something.

Thanks..

**EDIT**

`querySub` method

```
public Cursor querySub(String sub) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, sAllColumns, "ssub like " + "'" + sub + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        return cursor;
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor;
}
```

`Error Log`

```
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{an.droid.kit/an.droid.kit.DetailsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ArrayAdapter
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:     android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ArrayAdapter
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at an.droid.kit.DetailsActivity.dbToUI(DetailsActivity.java:217)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at an.droid.kit.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:104)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-05 12:11:14.144: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you also post code from querySub method and the error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too encountered a similar problem. **The issue**: I had to set the spinner to a particular string value without knowing what position that string value was in the spinner control itself. The work around that I created was to take the spinner control and cycle through its text values. At each position compare the spinners text value to the given string value that I wanted to set it to. If it matches then get that current position and set my spinners selection based on that position.

```
int spinnerPosition = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < yourSpinner.getCount(); i++) 
{
     Cursor cur = (Cursor)(yourSpinner.getItemAtPosition(i));

     //--When your bind you data to the spinner to begin with, whatever columns you
     //--used you will need to reference it in the cursors getString() method...

     //--Since "getString()" returns the value of the requested column as a String-- 
     //--(In my case) the 4th column of my spinner contained all of my text values 
     //--hence why I set the index of "getString()" method to "getString(3)"

     String currentSpinnerString = cur.getString(3).toString();
     if(currentSpinnerString.contains("place string you want to set the spinner to here"))
     {
        //--get the spinner position--
        spinnerPosition = i;
        break;
      }
 }

 yourSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: Worked great... Does exactly what I was aiming for... I had thought of this too but wasn't able to implement it successfully... Thanks for your help..:)

Comment: Oh yeah... use ' if(currentSpinnerString.equals("place string you want to set the spinner to here"))'
 to check for the exact string or else if you have a string that has the same characters as  another value in the column then it'll get the 1st value that contains the substring

Comment: @cking24343 yeah, you'd want to use `equals` instead of `contains` I'd assume?

Comment: @Matt Crinklaw-Vogt, you can. I just used `contains` in this instance but yeah it prob would be better to use `equals`. Thanks!